# Is there any way to track transactions of all POJO events?

Tags: perfino

I've been using perfino for a week, first thing I noticed is that there was no transactions being recorded, which is fine because all of our tools don't use any framework or special annotations that perfino could potentially detect.

When I saw POJO events transactions, I thought that I could just tell it to include all packages that we make here with a wildcard and have those analyzed.

It seems like perfino doesn't accept wildcards when adding a pojo class name.

Is there anything that I'm missing that I could do to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perfino deliberately does not have wildcards for classes since that would be an easy way to introduce unacceptable overhead. A transaction should be a high level use case, creating transactions for each method call is something that perfino is not designed for. You can see method-level data from all packages in the "Method sampling" view.

However you can instrument entire class hierarchies with the "Intercept subclasses" option on the POJO transaction configuration.